# Finding probability of an unfair coin

Tags: probability

An unfair coin is tossed giving heads with probability $p$ and tails with probability $1-p$. How many tosses do we have to perform if we want to find $p$ with a **desired accuracy**?

There is an obvious bound of $N$ tosses for $\lfloor \log_{10}{N} \rfloor$ digits of $p$; is there a better bound?

Comment: Can you explain the obvious bound? I'm curious.

Comment: @GWu: $\lfloor\log_{10}{N}\rfloor$ is how many decimal digits number $1/N$ has. It is also how much a $N$th toss will influence your knowledge of $p$.

Answer (score 5):

This is a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  The standard deviation on the number of heads is $\sqrt{Np(1-p)}$, so leaving aside the difference between your measured $p$ and the real $p$ you need $N \gt \frac{p(1-p)}{accuracy^2}$

Comment: But I don't know $p$; I want accuracy as a function of $N$ only.

Comment: @Eelvex: The function is maximised when $p=1/2$ so use that. If you want accuracy to mean $k$ standard deviations rather than just 1, take $N > \left(\dfrac{k}{2 \times \text{accuracy} }\right)^2$.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to find $p$ by tossing the coin with an accuracy like for the deterministic problems. That's a Monte-Carlo simulation and hence you better use bounds for these methods. Note that these bounds are probabilistic. E.g.
$$
\mathsf{P}(|p-\hat{p}_n|>\delta)\leq 2\mathrm{e}^{-2n\delta^2}
$$
where $\hat{p}_n$ can be obtained as a frequency of heads from tossing the coin $n$ times, i.e.
$$
\hat{p}_n = \frac{1}{n}\#( \text{heads in the tossing sequence} ).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your 'obvious bound' is incorrect. You cannot place absolute bounds on the value of p, regardless of the size of N.

However, as you increase N, your *confidence* improves in your calculated $p=N_{heads}/N$. Theoretically, though improbably, you could get 250 heads from 1000 throws of a fair coin.

You need to carry out a hypothesis test under the binomial distribution using a confidence interval of your choosing.